# bash filter/strip output for specific text

Tags: bash, sed, awk

Given the dmesg log output, specifically a line in it, for eg:

```
NET: Registered protocol family 10
```

in a script I want to have a defined variable like `$net_version` that will check if I define it with a value of 10, if it matches the one found in dmesg.

I looked both at sed and awk, however for awk I cannot find the correct way of stripping the output to just match the variable with the last word in that dmesg line.

I think this is a simple one, however I'm having an issue identifying the correct way of doing it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd advise against using unanchored regular expressions.  If "NET: Registered protocol family 100" is not supposed to be matched, then some of the other answers here may give you false positives.

In the following `grep` solution, note the anchor at the end of the regex.  Also, the `-q` option for grep makes it "quiet" so that it can be used simply to inform your `if`.

```
#!/bin/sh

val="10"

if dmesg | grep -q "^NET: Registered protocol family ${val}$"; then
  echo "matched"
fi
```

Alternately, you could use awk, but you'll want two conditions -- one to match the string on the line, and one to match the variable.

```
awk -v val="10" '/^NET: Registered protocol family / && $NF==val { print "matched" }'
```

Or you could do it with a single string match:

```
awk -v val="10" '$0 == "NET: Registered protocol family "val { print "matched" }'
```

or if you want to use `sed` to *strip* output for evaluation in a shell script, you could do it this way:

```
#!/bin/bash

val=$(dmesg | sed -ne '/^NET: Registered protocol family /{;s///p;q}')

if [ "$val" -eq "10" ]; then
  echo "matched"
fi
```

The sed script here looks a little complex, so lets' break it out...

- the `-n` option tells it not to print output by default,
- we start by searching for a line containing the NET: text, and if found,

  - we substitute the text we found for "nothing" (thus stripping it),
  - the `p` at the end of the command tells it to print the output if the substitution was successful, and
  - we quit, thus protecting ourselves from multiple occurrences of the string.

If instead you want to be able to handle multiple occurrences in your dmesg file, you might have to run things through a loop:

```
#!/bin/sh

dmesg \
 | sed -ne '/^NET: Registered protocol family /{;s///p;q}') \
 | while read val; do

     if [ "$val" -eq "10" ]; then
       echo "matched"
     fi

   done
```

I've split the dmesg pipe onto multiple lines for easier reading here, but you can make it all one line in your script.

Comment: Thanks a lot to both of you, the explanations were really helpful!

Answer (score 3):

You can use `sed` to print matching lines:

```
var=10
sed -n "/NET: Registered protocol family $var/p" file
```

- `-n` avoids printing all lines.
- `"/NET: .... $var/p"` users doubleq quotes to have the variable expanded.
- `/p` prints matched lines.

Or of course `grep`:

```
$ grep "NET: Registered protocol family $var" file
```

#### Example

```
$ cat a
NET: Registered protocol family 10
NET: Registered protocol family 7
NET: Registered protocol family hello
bye

$ var=10
$ sed -n "/NET: Registered protocol family $var/p" a
NET: Registered protocol family 10

$ var=7
$ sed -n "/NET: Registered protocol family $var/p" a
NET: Registered protocol family 7

$ var=5
$ sed -n "/NET: Registered protocol family $var/p" a
$
```

With `grep`:

```
$ var=10
$ grep "NET: Registered protocol family $var" a
NET: Registered protocol family 10
```

Answer (score 0):

Need to do similar thing but to find USB flash drive info.  I start with the command:

```
    dmesg | grep -i 'scsi' | grep -i removable
```

I get 2 results of:

```
    [    3.197914] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdc] Attached SCSI removable disk
    [22373.515566] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdd] Attached SCSI removable disk
```

I need to then loop to get the sdc and sdd values and plug into var $SDDRV to run next cmd of:

```
    fdisk -l | grep -i disk | grep ${SDDRV}
```

If the disk is not actually attached (this case sdc), the fdisk cmd produces nothing, but since in this case sdd is active, the result is:

```
    Disk /dev/sdd: 63.2 GB, 63216549888 bytes
```

I then need to parse out the flash drive size, which is 63.2 GB (My 64GB flash), and since size is greater that 63GB set var SDNAM to "64Gig" (name for flash).  I have a 1GB, 2GB, 16GB and 64GB, so must have logic to get the right name for any/all inserted drives and as you see the size linux sees does not equal the mfg size label.  Not sure why, but still need to get right name for each inserted device.

Next I need to run command:

```
    df -h | grep ${SDDRV}
```

Resulting in, I'm showing the column lables from 'df':

```
    Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
    /dev/sdd1        59G   11M   59G   1% /media/ndavis/USB DISK
```

From this I must parse the 'Available Space' and the 'Mount Point'

If I process all this right I then should have:

1. Drive Name,
2. Drive Size,
3. Space Available,
4. Mount Point

I then create a single VAR with all these and export it so this can be used by other scripts needing USB flash drive info.